# Firebase Data Structuring

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

we are building two Ionic apps at the startup I work for. We saw the benefit of rapid development that Firebase offers and we decided to use it as our backend. We are building hotel booking apps for users (people that want to search and book hotels) and for the hotels so that they can manage their bookings. The first app for the users is done and we have all our data and authentication rules stored at a Firebase Data URL. We are about to start building the second app meant for the hotels and we have some serious questions:

Should we use the same Firebase Data URL for the hotel app or should we create another one? If we use the same Firebase Data URL, that means data for the hotels and the users will be mixed and the URL will handle authentication for the entities.

Please we would really appreciate your input and opinions on best practices on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Not familiar with firebase, with in such sensitive domain as hotel booking, you want data of the two apps super-duper strongly consistent with each other. You don't want to let the user book a room in a sold-out hotel. The easiest way to ensure this consistency is to use the same database. With mysql, for example, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/xffAqT5auY0

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why you cannot use the same URL

```
myHotelAppRootNode
  Users
    someUser
    someUser
  Hotels
    someHotel
    someHotel
```

Then set up the rules to restrict access.

We have data and users in the same url in our beta app and it's not causing any mixing of data; as long as the rules are correct (which can be a bit challenging).

Using two URL's may slightly uncomplicate the rules per, but then you have multiple authentication points since it's two URL's. So say, once a user authenticated with a single URL model, they would then have access to hotel data directly whereas with two you have to auth them once, and then the app would need to auth them again to the second URL.